# Programa Crashando aleatoriamente

Tags: c++, lista

Estou trabalhando com Listas em C++ e, enquanto fazia o seguinte código de implementação de uma lista:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class NO{

    int idade;
    string nome;
    NO *no;

    public:

        void setDados(int, string);
        int getidade();
        string getnome();
        void setNext(NO*);
        NO* getNext();  
        ~NO(){};        

};

class Lista{

    NO *inicio;

    int quant_el;

    public:     

        Lista(){

            quant_el = 0;
            inicio->setNext(NULL);          

        }

        void inserir(int, string);  
        void pesquisar(NO); 
        void remover(int);
        void listar();      

};


void NO :: setDados(int idade, string nome)
{
    this->idade = idade;
    this->nome = nome;
}

int NO :: getidade()
{
    return idade;
}

string NO :: getnome()
{
    return nome;
}

void NO :: setNext(NO *no)
{
    this->no = no;
}

NO* NO :: getNext()
{
    return no;
}

void Lista :: inserir(int idade, string nome)
{
    NO *aux;
    aux = inicio;

    NO *novo = new NO();

    novo->setDados(idade, nome);
    novo->setNext(NULL);

    if(quant_el == 0)
    {
        inicio->setNext(novo);
        quant_el++;
    }
    else
    {
        while( (aux->getNext()) != NULL )
        {
            aux = aux->getNext();
        }
        aux->setNext(novo);
        quant_el++;
    }
    cout << "Foi inserido '" << idade << " " << nome << "'" << endl;
}

void Lista :: pesquisar(NO obj)
{
    NO *aux;

    int i;
    int cont = 1;
    int cont1 = 0;

    aux = inicio;

    if(quant_el == 0)
    {
        cout << "Não há nenhum dado na sua Lista." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = 0; i < quant_el; i++)
        {
            cont++;
            if(((aux->getNext())->getidade() == obj.getidade()) && ((aux->getNext()->getnome() == obj.getnome())))
            {
                cont1++;
                break;
            }
            aux = aux->getNext();
        }
        if(cont1 == 0)
        {
            cout << "O dado não foi encontrado." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Dado encontrado na posição " << cont - 1 << endl;
        }
    }
}

void Lista :: remover(int pos)
{
    int i;

    NO *aux, *aux1;
    aux = inicio;
    aux1 = aux->getNext();

    if(pos > quant_el)
    {
        if(quant_el == 0)
        {
            cout << "Sua lista está vazia, não há elementos para remover." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Posição inválida, sua lista possui menos elementos." << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++)
        {
            aux = aux1;
            aux1 = aux1->getNext();
        }
        aux->setNext(aux1->getNext());

        quant_el --;
        cout << "Dado " << i + 1  << " removido: " << endl << aux1->getidade() << " " << aux1->getnome() << endl << endl;
        delete aux1;
    }
}


void Lista :: listar()
{

    int i;

    NO *aux;

    aux = inicio;

    if(quant_el == 0)
    {
        cout << "Sua lista está vazia, não há elementos para mostrar." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = 1; i <= quant_el; i++)
        {
            cout << i << " Dado:" << endl;
            cout << aux->getNext()->getnome() << endl << aux->getNext()->getidade() << endl << endl;

            aux = aux->getNext();
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    Lista lista1;

    NO loiola, rangel, humb;

    loiola.setDados(18, "Loiola");
    rangel.setDados(29, "Eustáquio");
    humb.setDados(23, "Humberto");

    lista1.inserir(18, "Filipe");
    lista1.inserir(29, "Eustáquio");
    lista1.inserir(10000, "Raul Seixas");
    lista1.inserir(18, "Leticia");
    lista1.inserir(18, "Mayra");
    //lista1.inserir(23, "Humberto"); Se um nó a mais for inserido, o programa crasha


    lista1.pesquisar(loiola);   
    lista1.pesquisar(rangel);
    //lista1.pesquisar(loiola); Se um nó a mais for pesquisado, o programa crasha.

    lista1.remover(2);

    lista1.remover(3);

    lista1.remover(1);

    lista1.listar();

    lista1.listar(
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Também pode acessar em https://codeshare.io/5DvbWO

O programa começou a crashar do nada, ao pesquisar mais de 2 nós ou inserir mais de 5. Não há erros de compilação, o programa simplesmente crasha.

Alguém saberia dizer qual o problema?

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: O ideal seria colocar o código na publicação

Comment: O que você fez pra tentar corrigir o problema?

Comment: eu testei seu código (mas inicializei a variável "inicio" (inicio = new NO; // no construtor) senão ele parava logo no começo da execução) e funcionou descomentando as duas linhas que você mostrou. Quando ocorre o "crash" qual mensagem mostra?

Answer (score 0):

Precisa de acertar várias coisas no seu código:

- No construtor da lista está a fazer `setNext` sobre o `No` `inicio` que nem sequer foi instanciado:

  ```
  Lista() {
      quant_el = 0;
      inicio->setNext(NULL); //<-- aqui
  }
  ```

  Uma vez que acabou de construir a lista melhor será não construir o nó de inicio até que seja adicionado um nó. Por isso precisa apenas de remover a instrução que assinalei.
- Ainda referente a casos iniciais, no seu método de `inserir` quando não tem ainda elementos e de acordo com a solução que dei no ponto anterior não pode utilizar ponteiro `inicio`.

  ```
  if(quant_el == 0)
  {
      inicio->setNext(novo); //<---aqui
      quant_el++;
  }
  ```

  Pois quando `quant_el` é `0` `inicio` não foi ainda alocado. Basta trocar por:

  ```
  if(quant_el == 0)
  {
      inicio = novo;
      quant_el++;
  }
  ```

  Assim o primeiro nó será o `inicio`. O próprio incremento `quant_el++;` está a ser feito tanto no `if` como no `else` e por isso pode simplificar retirando nos dois e fazendo a seguir a esse bloco.
- Na pesquisa está a utilizar o nó da frente para fazer as comparações uma vez que chama com `->getNext()`:

  ```
  if(((aux->getNext())->getidade() == obj.getidade()) && ((aux->getNext()->getnome() == obj.getnome())))
  //---------^------------------------------------------------------^
  ```

  Isto faz com que no ultimo teste o nó da frente, que é `NULL` e crashe com *segmentation fault*. Simplifique nos parêntesis e teste com o próprio nó:

  ```
  if(aux->getidade() == obj.getidade() && aux->getnome() == obj.getnome()) {
  ```
- No método `listar` caiu no mesmo problema de mostrar o elemento da frente em vez do elemento corrente:

  ```
  cout << aux->getNext()->getnome() << endl << aux->getNext()->getidade() << endl << endl;
  //-------------^-------------------------------------^
  ```

  Que corrige facilmente removendo apenas os `->getNext()`.

  Chamo também a atenção para o for que construiu que começa em `1` e termina igual ao valor de `quant_el`:

  ```
  for(i = 1; i <= quant_el; i++)
  //------^-----^
  ```

  Normalmente começa em `0` e executa enquanto é menor, algo muito comum para arrays. Da forma que fez tem tendencia a causar problemas, mas como neste caso particular este valor apenas é utilizado para mostrar na tela acaba não ter impacto.

[Veja o código com estas alterações todas e a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/SWBxUD)